# How to use XML mapping for single entity and keep the rest of entities mapped by Annotations?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.8

I am adding new functionality ([hackzilla/Ticket-bundle](https://github.com/hackzilla/TicketBundle)) to the old App based on Symfony 2.8 and I need to extend the basic entities of this bundle to be able to add some custom fields.

In the App all entities are using Annotations for mapping, but to extend entities from Ticket-bundle I most likely need to use XML mapping, based on this [doc](https://github.com/hackzilla/TicketBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/setup/feature/custom-entities.md).

Is there a way to use XML mapping for single/multiple entities, but not for all of them?

This is my current doctrine configuration.

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        dql:
           datetime_functions:
               month: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\Month
               monthname: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\MonthName
               ifnull: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\IfNull
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to disable `doctrine.orm.auto_mapping` and instead map entities manually. It could look something like thisc (you can omit some of these options, check the linked documentation for a shorter example when using bundles):

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: true
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/AppBundle/Entity'
                prefix: 'AppBundle\Entity'
                alias: App
            Ticket:
                is_bundle: true
                type: xml
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/TicketBundle/Entity'
                prefix: 'TicketBundle\Entity'
                alias: Ticket
```

See also: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#mapping-configuration